# nvarchar lenght update from one table to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, nvarchar

'''i have two table in MSSQL. produktion_test and Angebotpos_test . the number of column in each table are not equal.
but there are some items , for example SBesch01,SBesch02, SBesch03,...
in Angebotpos_test table there are column like SBesch01, SBesch02, SBesch03 , data type is nvarchar(20)----in produktion_test are same column SBesch01,SBesch02,SBesch03 but data type is nvarchar(50) , i need a script which find the data type (nvarchar) in angebotpos_test which are smaller than the same column in produktion _test , and update the lenght of (nvarchar) and set it same to produktion_test table !

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  In addition, your explanation is not clear.

Comment: in Angebotpos_test table there are column like SBesch01, SBesch02, SBesch03 , data type is nvarchar(20)----in produktion_test are same column SBesch01,SBesch02,SBesch03 but data type is nvarchar(50) , i need a script which find the data type (nvarchar) in angebotpos_test which are smaller than the same column in produktion _test , and update the lenght of (nvarchar) and set it same to produktion_test table !

Comment: . . You can edit the question to make it clearer.  The information belongs in the *question* not in a comment.

Comment: i did-thanks . i hope to find an answer !